# When a 100m long straight garden hose sprays water, is there any reaction force?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

When a 100m long straight garden hose sprays water, is there any reaction force? Where is the acting point of the force?

Someone explained it with the conservation of momentum. But I have questions:
Water moves at a constant speed in the garden hose, because the 100 meter hose is of equal diameter, right? So there is no momentum change.

If there is momentum change at the water pump, and the acting point of the force is at the water pump, why does the outlet of the garden hose slide back and forth?

Comment: Why is the length significant?

Comment: @PM2Ring Avoid some people saying that the reaction force is the result of hose bending.

Comment: @Dale What explanation do you think is right?